# Explain an algorithm to rotate a N X N matrix by 90 degree

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an algorithm that rotates a N X N matrix by 90 degree. It works but slightly hard for me to understand. Anyone can explain it to me in details ? Thanks.

```
 public static void rotate(int[][] matrix, int n) {

        for (int layer = 0; layer < n / 2; ++layer) {

            int first = layer;
            int last = n - 1 - layer;

            for(int i = first; i < last; ++i) {

                int offset = i - first;
                int top = matrix[first][i]; // save top

                // left -> top
                matrix[first][i] = matrix[last-offset][first];          

                // bottom -> left
                matrix[last-offset][first] = matrix[last][last - offset]; 

                // right -> bottom
                matrix[last][last - offset] = matrix[i][last]; 

                // top -> right
                matrix[i][last] = top; // right <- saved top
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use *debug* mode in your IDE, to understand it better, with the actual flow, just as a suggestion :)

Comment: The given algorithm is downright slick, assuming that it works for all matrices, which I have little doubt that it does. If it works as I suggest below, it's an obvious way to do it, but tough to code and tougher to *de*code.

Comment: @Teepeem yup, you're right, i just went fully retarded

Comment: I upvoted her; it's a good question, taken at face value. I just don't get all the downvotes without comment. You'll note that it's marked as a favoite by three people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Submitted for your approval. Run it as is and study the output and think about running bases clockwise. Seriously.

Let me know if it helped. It was fun to explore for me.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class NewMain1 {

 static int[][] m ;

 public static void rotate(int[][] matrix, int n) {

        for (int layer = 0; layer < n / 2; ++layer) {

            int first = layer;
            int last = n - 1 - layer;

            for(int i = first; i < last; ++i) {

                int offset = i - first;
                int top = matrix[first][i]; // save top
                // left -> top
                matrix[first][i] = matrix[last-offset][first]; 
                printmove(last-offset,first,first,i);

                // bottom -> left
                printmove(last,last-offset,last-offset,first);
                matrix[last-offset][first] = matrix[last][last - offset]; 

                // right -> bottom
                printmove(i,last,last,last-offset);
                matrix[last][last - offset] = matrix[i][last]; 

                // top -> right
                printmove(first,i,i,last);
                matrix[i][last] = top; // right <- saved top
                System.out.println("");
                printmatrix(matrix,n);
                System.out.println("");
              try{
                int s = System.in.read();
              } catch (IOException ex){ }
            }
        }
    }

 static void printmove(int r1, int c1, int r2, int c2){
    System.out.println("["+(r1+1)+"]["+(c1+1)+ "] moves to [" + (r2+1) + "][" + (c2+1) + "]");
 }

 static void printmatrix(int[][] m, int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        System.out.print(m[i][j] + " ");
       }
      System.out.println("");
   }
 }

  static void makematrix(int[][] m, int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        m[i][j] = 10*(i+1) + j+1;
       }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 6;
    int[][] m = new int[n][n];
    makematrix(m, n);
    printmatrix(m, n);
    rotate(m,n);
    System.out.println("");
    printmatrix(m, n);
 }

}
```

E.g.:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this data:

```
 static int[][] m = {{11,12,13,14},{21,22,23,24},{31,32,33,34},{41,42,43,44}};
```

And add this code after the last `matrix` line in `rotate`:

```
            System.out.println("");
            printmatrix(matrix,n);
            System.out.println("");
          try{
            int s = System.in.read();
          } catch (IOException ex){

          }
```

And use this routine to print matrix at each iteration:

```
 static void printmatrix(int[][] m, int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        System.out.print(m[i][j] + " ");
       }
      System.out.println("");
   }

 }
```

Use this `main`:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    printmatrix(m, 4);
    rotate(m,4);
    System.out.println("");
    printmatrix(m, 4);
 }
```

And just observe which elements "moved" during each iteration:

*EDIT* Forget the above.

Refer to my 2nd answer for visual explanation.

Comment: You'll have to position the cursor in the output window and hit enter to get from one `printmatrix` to the next.