# rotating a 2d array and returnd 2d array by rotating 90°

Tags: java, arrays, rotation

Write a java method rotate that takes a two-dimensional array a and returns a two-dimensional array b made by rotating a by 90° counterclockwise

like :

5    6    7

8    9   10

after rotation will be :

7     10

6      9

5      8

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: can you rearrange the numbers in the array so that it looks like a 2D array, not just a list of numbers?

Comment: Please edit your question to correct the formatting of the source arry sample. Currently it is indicating 1x6 array (not truly 2d).  Do you want to rotate a m*n matrix to get a n*m matrix or another m*n with relocated elements?

Comment: Although [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31485540/2737933) applies only to rotating square matrix, you might find it helpful. (By the way, SO isn't here to write code assigned in homework problems.)

Answer (score 0):

Try multiplying it to a rotation matrix (linear algebra)

Comment: Are you sure there exists one for non-square matrix? I'm not sure either way.